# Citing Math Lesson Plans

Tags: citations, mathematics, legal-issues, citation-style

If I am creating lesson plans, do I need to cite the various websites I use for my work? It is for math, and the information I have used is found in thousands of sites. I have not taken any lesson plans, nor have I taken their math problems and claimed them as my own. I instead used the different websites and textbooks as a placeholder of "what do I talk about next". For example, I am on a site talking about multiplying whole numbers. The websites example is "256 times 5". I see that, and go okay how about "163 times 3".

Whether I do or do not cite, can I have my name on the lesson plans? So far, I have read if I use citations I can; "This work has been collected and combined by name".

Which brings me to my last question. If I do need to cite, can I create a work-cited page and put all my references on that page, or do I HAVE to put in-text citations? This is not for any kind of class; I am making this to help my fellow students.

Thank you for your time,

Samantha

Comment: For what purpose are you creating lesson plans?  A math / education course?  If so, probably the best answer is to ask your instructor.

Comment: Also depends on your students level? Masters or undergraduate or lower.

Comment: You may also want to ask at http://matheducators.stackexchange.com which may have a different set of people chiming in.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to cite the various websites I use for my work?

It depends on the *work* your are referring to. In your case, it is math lessons. One ought to cite for one or of the following [reasons](http://libguides.mit.edu/citing). Let's look at whether these points apply to you.

1. **To show you've done enough research**. You wouldn't have to prove to your students that you've done enough research; the study content should be sufficient.
2. **To give credit for the source of the work**. Is your work publicly available? Would it anyhow increase the citation count of the author you intend to credit? If so, it would be up to you.
3. **To avoid plagiarism**. You are not plagiarizing as you are not claiming the work to be your own; you are teaching what is established.
4. **To allow readers to track the sources for further information**. Do you feel that your students would have the need to go through the sources you've referred? If so, you wouldn't have to cite all of them, but only the ones you feel are important.

> Whether I do or do not cite, can I have my name on the lesson plans?

Yes, as long as you don't claim the work to be novel in any way (which you obviously won't be doing). It would be better to add a disclaimer as you stated in your post like *"This work has been collected and combined by name"*.

> Can I create a work-cited page and put all my references on that page, or do I HAVE to put in-text citations?

That would be actually useful, a work-cited page can be referred by avid students who would want to receive more information on the topic. But in-text citations would be have to be a matter of preference, that depends on the utility of the majority of your students.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sharing this document with students, then I would ask what information would benefit them. A link to further reading, sure; where you got the inspiration for a type of question? Probably not.